# how to receive multiple same name checkbox value and insert into db in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I need to receive multiple same name checkbox value and insert into db in laravel 5.2.

My Table row : tagname, postid

Advance Thanks .

Comment: is this actually a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example :

```
<form action="{{url('submitdata')}}" method="post">
{!!csrf_field()!!}
<lavel  for="subject1">Bangla</label> 
 <input id="subject1" name="subject[]"  type="checkbox" value="Bangla"/>
<lavel  for="subject1">English</label>
<input id="subject1" name="subject[]"  type="checkbox" value="English"/>
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
<public function insert(Request $r){

foreach($r->get('subject') AS $k=>$v){

 DB::table('subject')->insert([

'subject'=>$r->get('subject')[$k]

 ]);
}
}
```